# Use of undeclared identifier FLT_MAX when used in macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I use the following code to dynamically resize labels:

```
CGRect frame = self.myLabel2.frame;
frame.origin.y = self.myLabel1.frame.origin.y + self.myLabel1.frame.size.height + 10;
frame.size = LABEL_SIZE(self.myLabel2);
self.myLabel2.frame = frame;
```

Where `LABEL_SIZE` is a macro defined as :

```
#define LABEL_SIZE(label) CGSizeMake(280, [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(280, FLT_MAX)].height);
```

The code works absolutely fine when run on simulator (32-bit). The problem arises when running  on simulator (64-bit). XCode shows it *not* as a warning, but as an **error**, due to which, it will not even compile.

I do not understand, am I missing something?

Comment: show `FLT_MAX` macro definition.

Comment: FLT_MAX is a built-in macro defined in float.h.

Comment: FLT_MAX is a maximum value of float. use when you want to find number with comparison of max value

Comment: @SunnyShah, how is that relevant to the issue?

Comment: I don't know if you have tried other links before posting the question, but this link has exact what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285188/is-there-a-constant-for-the-maximum-cgfloat-value

Comment: @Tarun, that question is not **remotely** related to what I had asked. Mine is a compilation error. I know `CGGeometry` defines. Anyway, I solved this issue of mine a long time back.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `float.h`

```
#include <float.h>
float a = FLT_MAX;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of `FLT_MAX` as show below

```
#define LABEL_SIZE(label) CGSizeMake((CGFloat)280, [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake((CGFloat)280, (CGFLOAT_MAX))].height);
```